# how to use established ssh session?

Tags: linux, ssh, gateway

I have Linux (Server1) in remote location, can't connect to it from the Net, becuase it has dynamic IP and is behind router/nat. However Server1 is under mine control (regarding software it has) and I have another Linux Server2 (VPS) with public IP. Can Server1 connect to Server2 in such a way that when I log into my Server2 I will be able to use this connection to log into Server1 ?

So on Server1 I'm using:

```
ssh -R 12345:Sever1:2222 root@Server2
```

where port 2222 is where ssh is listening on Server1 Once ssh connections is established on Server2 I can execute:

```
ssh -p 12345 -v user@localhost
```

And I have this output

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 12345.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u1
```

so looks like almost there ;) on Server2 connections to port 12345 is forwarded via tunnel to Server1 port 2222 , some ssh is listening but there is no authentication, why ?

Best Regards
Marek

Comment: Have you considered a DDNS [Dynamic DNS] service, which would allow you to access Server 1 directly?

Comment: DDNS will not work, because Server1 is beghind firewall/nat and I cannot initiate connection from Server2 to Server1. But it looks like it works after I have generated keys (ssh-keygen) and set these in authorized_keys file in .ssh directory of each host I can connect to Server1 from Server2 after Server1 starts the ssh with tunnel (no passwords needed). But thanks for comment

Comment: Are you unable to configure a port redirect in the firewall Server 1 is downstream from for DDNS?

Comment: @JW0914 - The author has indicated they already solved the problem by uploading the keys to the server.